# Error during incremental deploy with Netbeans on WildFly app server

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly, web-deployment, wildfly-8

I'm using NetBeans version 8.1 with WildFly 8.1.0.. From WSDL file I have developed a webservice. When I try to run the webservice for the second time I got:

> Deployment error: Error during incremental deploy: java.io.IOException: C:/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/WebservisPolicija3.war

I tried to clean and rebuild the project but the problem still remains..

Is there some other way to redeploy? Or something else to try?

Comment: and what is full exception? Did you try with any newer version of wildfly? 8.1 is quite old...

Comment: The problem was a missing library.. I have a (test) connection to my database over JDBC and forget to add jdbc library to my project...

Comment: I frequently see this error as well - but for me executing a "Clean and Build" temporarily fixes it.  The error comes back pretty frequently though.  Seems like Netbeans integration with Wildfly is not quite right.

Answer (score 3):

clean and build your project and then run it again!