# Netbeans cannot deploy projects on Wildfly server

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly

I'm using NetBeans version 13 with WildFly 26.0.1 Final.. I have developed a webservice and when I try to run the webservice for the second time I get:

```
Error during incremental deploy: java.io.IOException: C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ReportGenerator.war
C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ReportGenerator\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1071
```

build-impl.xml:1071:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

I tried looking for solutions on stackoverflow [Error during incremental deploy with Netbeans on WildFly app server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241112/error-during-incremental-deploy-with-netbeans-on-wildfly-app-server), uninstall and reinstall netbeans, change the version of wildfly but in vain.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPMN2.png)

[Server log whenever I clear it trying to figure out the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPMN2.png)

Server log when starting server and deploying the project (It gives the same error):

```
    Calling "C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,DESKTOP-OTEN3N6 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,DESKTOP-OTEN3N6 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080  --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/javax.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming=ALL-UNNAMED"

===============================================================================

13:06:04,287 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 2.0.0.Final
13:06:04,908 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.13.Final
13:06:04,938 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
13:06:05,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 26.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) starting
13:06:06,078 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.18.3.Final
13:06:07,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found DataEntry.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called DataEntry.war.dodeploy
13:06:07,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found ReportGenerator.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called ReportGenerator.war.dodeploy
13:06:07,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:06:07,163 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.8.5.Final
13:06:07,177 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.5.Final
13:06:07,233 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 4.7.4.Final
13:06:07,250 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
13:06:07,250 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.jwt.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYJWT0001: Activating MicroProfile JWT Subsystem
13:06:07,254 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYCONF0001: Activating MicroProfile Config Subsystem
13:06:07,258 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron.oidc._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYOIDC0001: Activating WildFly Elytron OIDC Subsystem
13:06:07,271 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.health] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Base Health Subsystem
13:06:07,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:06:07,300 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
13:06:07,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following Jakarta Server Faces Implementations: [main]
13:06:07,313 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.metrics] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Base Metrics Subsystem
13:06:07,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:06:07,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
13:06:07,457 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
13:06:07,545 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.14.Final starting
13:06:07,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
13:06:07,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting Jakarta Connectors Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.5.3.Final)
13:06:07,644 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
13:06:07,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
13:06:07,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:06:07,717 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file 'C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
13:06:07,794 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
13:06:07,798 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
13:06:07,806 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 IO threads with 128 max task threads based on your 8 available processors
13:06:07,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
13:06:07,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
13:06:07,968 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
13:06:07,971 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) Queuing requests.
13:06:07,978 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
13:06:08,011 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.23.Final
13:06:08,142 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
13:06:08,289 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
13:06:08,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
13:06:08,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:06:08,649 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
13:06:08,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
13:06:08,710 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:06:08,717 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
13:06:08,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "ReportGenerator.war" (runtime-name: "ReportGenerator.war")
13:06:08,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "DataEntry.war" (runtime-name: "DataEntry.war")
13:06:08,894 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.4.5) 
13:06:08,938 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\Users\Kareem Elagroudy\Documents\wildfly-26.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
13:06:09,021 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
13:06:09,272 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
13:06:09,274 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
13:06:09,275 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
13:06:09,275 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
13:06:09,504 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
13:06:09,504 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
13:06:11,751 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue on address jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
13:06:11,763 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue jms.queue.DLQ on address jms.queue.DLQ
13:06:11,766 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
13:06:11,766 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
13:06:11,766 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
13:06:11,767 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
13:06:12,217 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221007: Server is now live
13:06:12,217 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.19.0 [default, nodeID=7d7060a0-b515-11ec-bd18-60f26273bf4a] 
13:06:12,246 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
13:06:12,248 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
13:06:12,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
13:06:12,431 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRALogger] (MSC service thread 1-7) AMQ151007: Resource adaptor started
13:06:12,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-7) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
13:06:12,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0002: Bound Jakarta Connectors ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
13:06:12,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0118: Binding connection factory named java:/JmsXA to alias java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
13:06:14,147 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment ReportGenerator.war
13:06:14,302 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.22.Final
13:06:14,768 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-8) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
13:06:14,771 INFO  [org.wildfly.microprofile.opentracing.smallrye] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYTRAC0001: Tracer initialized: JaegerTracer(version=Java-1.6.0, serviceName=ReportGenerator.war, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing.spi.sender.WildFlySender@28c99c06, closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=DESKTOP-OTEN3N6, jaeger.version=Java-1.6.0, ip=192.168.1.201}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
13:06:15,133 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Taedonggang' 12.1.7.Final
13:06:15,182 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:06:15,183 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:06:15,237 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
13:06:15,259 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 3.1.8 (Final)
13:06:15,379 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) ISPN000025: wakeUpInterval is <= 0, not starting expired purge thread
13:06:15,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
13:06:15,592 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry com.ibm.mq.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,592 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jms.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,592 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry rmm.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,593 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jndi.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,593 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry ldap.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,593 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry fscontext.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,593 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry providerutil.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,593 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry dhbcore.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,594 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry CL3Export.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:15,594 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry CL3Nonexport.jar in /C:/Users/Kareem Elagroudy/Documents/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/DataEntry.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:06:16,050 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment DataEntry.war
13:06:16,292 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-5) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
13:06:16,293 INFO  [org.wildfly.microprofile.opentracing.smallrye] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYTRAC0001: Tracer initialized: JaegerTracer(version=Java-1.6.0, serviceName=DataEntry.war, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing.spi.sender.WildFlySender@37cf1f97, closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=DESKTOP-OTEN3N6, jaeger.version=Java-1.6.0, ip=192.168.1.201}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
13:06:16,397 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.17.SP01 for context '/ReportGenerator'
13:06:16,522 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
13:06:16,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
13:06:16,525 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.DataEntry_war_oracle_jdbc_OracleDriver_11_2 is already registered
13:06:16,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = DataEntry.war
13:06:16,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = DataEntry.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_11_2
13:06:16,954 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 107) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.17.SP01 for context '/DataEntry'
13:06:18,133 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) Running on PrimeFaces 11.0.0
13:06:18,183 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/ReportGenerator' for server 'default-server'
13:06:18,323 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 107) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
13:06:18,324 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 107) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/DataEntry' for server 'default-server'
13:06:18,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ReportGenerator.war" (runtime-name : "ReportGenerator.war")
13:06:18,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "DataEntry.war" (runtime-name : "DataEntry.war")
13:06:18,491 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
13:06:18,493 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) 
    WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 26.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) 
    started in 14611ms - Started 1191 of 1392 services (361 services are 
    lazy, passive or on-demand)
    13:06:18,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) 
    WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on 
    http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    13:06:18,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) 
    WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

Note: I'm using JDK 18

Comment: We need more of the error - the IOException should have additional information.

Comment: @stdunbar Unfortunately, this is the only provided info. The server log is blank whenever this error occurs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans but it looks like there is a way to turn additional information on for the ant output level.  The link I found is 14 years old so I don't know if it's still relevant but it says under Tools->Options there is a Misc tab to change the output level.  Make it verbose.  Otherwise, if you use the command line, run with `ant -v` to build.

Comment: @stdunbar It's not there unfortunately but in order to run any webapp project after any modification, I have to clean and build the project

Comment: @KareemAlaa [1] Update your question your Java version. (Only LTS releases are supported for WildFly 26.) [2] When you say _"The server log is blank whenever this error occurs"_, do you mean that there is literally nothing in the server log at all, or that you don't see anything in the log that is relevant because nothing is written to the log during deployment? If it is the latter then post the log in text form anyway, since the error message explicitly states that details are in the server log. [3] Is your WildFly server working normally otherwise?

Comment: If you are using JDK 18 when you run NetBeans, then you will also be using JDK18 when you run WildFly 26 within NetBeans. But WildFly 26.0.1 does not support the use of JDK 18, and its release (1/21/22) preceded the release of JDK 18 (3/22/22) by two months. So regardless of whether you have any specific problems, you should be using JDK 17, not JDK 18, to run WildFly. So downgrade NetBeans to run on JDK 17 to see if that resolves your issue. It may, or it may not, but the environment you have now is simply not supported (even if it seems to work most of the time).

Comment: Also, [WildFly 26.1 Beta](https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/) was released on 3/24/22, though [its release notes](https://issues.redhat.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12380362&styleName=Html&projectId=12313721&Create=Create&atl_token=AQZJ-FV3A-N91S-UDEU_3da0364308ab61211e2b1acfef344a3afe2e7ca7_lout) also don't mention anything about explicit support for JDK 18.

Comment: I'll try it and thank you in advance